# Pyside6 GUI Freezing in python

Tags: python, user-interface, pyside6

I am developing a software for my academic application, as soon as I run the phaseidentification engine the GUI freezes. I have tried to transfer the functions to threads but it does not work. What should I do to prevent this GUI from freezing when running the worker engine?

This is the main GUI class:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_PhaseIdentification):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Initialization
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.worker = PhaseIdentificationSolve(self)


    def bind(self):
        # Other function bind
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.mainPhaseIdentification)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.showResult)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.showResult) # Display the result of phaseidentification
```

This is the worker class:

```
class PhaseIdentificationSolve(QObject):
    finished = Signal()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PhaseIdentificationSolve, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.exceptTrap = False

    def mainPhaseIdentification(self):
        # Main phaseidentification engine
        self.finished.emit()
```

Comment: "I have tried to transfer the functions to threads": what functions? Your code has nothing else than a signal emit. Please provide a [mre].